# Dimensional Modeling Doubts

Tags: dimensional-modeling

I have a few questions regarding dimensional modeling:

1. While designing dimensional model from existing OLTP system, do we use the same table structures in OLTP in dimension model? For example I have a customer table in OLTP and I want to include it in my dimensional model, so can I use the same table structure while designing a customer dimension table or I can change it?
2. Can dimension tables refer each other? For example, in my OLTP I have EMP and DEPT table, EMP references DEPT, so I choose these two tables to be part of dimensional model, is it necessary that I put a FK constraint on EMP dimensional table?
3. Now, about bridge table, suppose in my OLTP I have STORE and DEPT tables and a bridge table STORE_DEPT that joins STORE with DEPT, that means I can have multiple departments within each store which is recorded in this bride table. Now, suppose I want to create dimension tables for STORE and DEPT in my dimensional model, do I need to include this bridge table also in the model?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, dimensions should be fully de-normalised - so you shouldn't be doing any bridge tables or joins between them.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, the dimensional model is usually very different from the OLTP schema.  You'll want to read about star schemas.
2. I would say that dimensions are usually independent of each other.  I wouldn't start by having them refer to each other.  If you think they need to, then redesign.
3. STORE and DEPT sound like they should be part of a LOCATION dimension.  I still see no need for a bridge or JOIN.

You sound like you're trying to design your first star schema.  It might be a good idea to seek out some training or guidance.

Comment: duffymo: Thank you so much for the reply. Yes this is first time I am trying to design dimension model though I have experience designing for OLTP systems. I have also a little theoretical knowledge of dimensional modeling. So I guess I can design dimension tables independent of OLTP table designs as long as I can populate them with proper data from OLTP system right? Also, as you have suggested may be I can try combining STORE and DEPT to make one dimension table and avoid bridge table? Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: I'm a Kimball fan.  Check out his books for advice on dimensional modeling.